# What does VS Code's debug.enableAllHovers setting do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out what the VS Code's setting `debug.enableAllHovers` does. I can't see any difference, while debugging, between having it set to `true` or `false`.

Can someone please explain what this setting does?

Here's a [video explaining my doubt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXJzwusJyVI&list=PLVwLx67OHLu1HIbCihg3cohaM5eCarbiQ&index=39).

Comment: It’s intended to assist debugging custom VSC extensions. Are you building your own VSC extension?

Comment: @Dai are you sure? The setting's description says nothing about custom extensions. Would you be able to provide an example use-case?

Answer (score 0):

The debug.enableAllHovers setting was [added as a workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/3242) for the LiveShare extension which [no longer uses it](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3002) and also seems to have no plans to use it in the future.

I suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97153) we remove this setting from VS Code entirely.